# Closure and limit of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $E$ be a subset of a metric space $(S,d)$. I'm trying to show that an element is in $\overline{E}$ if and only if it is the limit of some sequence of points in $E$.

Suppose there is a sequence $(p_n) \subseteq E$. Then because $E \subseteq \overline{E}$, I know that $(p_n) \subseteq \overline{E}$. Since $\overline{E}$ is closed, $\overline{E}$ contains the limit of every convergent sequence of points in $\overline{E}$. So $p \in \overline{E}.$

This is how I approached the converse: I assumed $p \in \overline{E}$ and that there does not exist a sequence $(p_n) \subseteq E$ such that $p_n \to p$. Then I concluded that there exists  $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $d(p, x) \geq \varepsilon \ \forall x \in E$.

Then there exists an open ball centered at $p$ that does not contain a point of $E$ (I wasn't sure how to make this statement rigorous). So $p \notin \overline{E}$.

Could I get some feedback on my proof?

Comment: What is your definition of $\overline{E}$?

Comment: @ZevChonoles $\overline{E} = \bigcap \{ C \ | \ E \subseteq C; C \text{ closed} \}$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven’t actually justified the conclusion that there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $d(p,x)\ge\epsilon$ for each $x\in E$. Justifying it properly requires essentially the same work as a direct proof that if $p\in\operatorname{cl}E$, then there is a sequence $\langle p_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ in $E$ converging to $p$, so you might as well give the direct proof.

There are two cases.

1. If $p\in E$, there’s a trivial sequence in $E$ that converges to $p$; what is it?
2. If $p\in(\operatorname{cl}E)\setminus E$, you have to work just a little bit. For each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ there’s a point $p_n\in E$ such that $d(p,p_n)<\frac1n$; why? What does this get you?

Comment: For 1. I see that I can just take $(p_n)$ where $p_n = p$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. But I don't understand the second hint. Could you explain why there exists points $p_n \in E$ such that $d(p, p_n) < 1/n$? If this is true then I get a sequence in $E$ that converges to $p$.

Comment: @Student: You’re right about (1), and you’ve drawn the correct conclusion from (2). For the missing step, recall that $p\in\operatorname{cl}E$ iff every open ball centred at $p$ has non-empty intersection with $E$.

Comment: I get it! Thank you for the help again! My real analysis book actually does not mention that $p \in \overline{E} \iff \forall \varepsilon > 0, B(p, \varepsilon) \cap E \neq \emptyset$. Do you recommend any books on metric spaces/topology?

Comment: @Student: You’re welcome! One of the best and most widely-used undergraduate topology texts is James Munkres, [*Topology*](http://www.amazon.com/Topology-2nd-James-Munkres/dp/0131816292); it has far more than you need for beginning real analysis, but I think that you’d find the parts that *are* immediately relevant fairly accessible.

Answer (score 1):

The result is always true in the first countable space. Note that every metric space is first countable.

> Let $X$ be first countable and $E$ is a subset of $X$. If $p∈\bar{E}$ iff there  exists a sequence $(p_n)⊆E$ such that $p_n→p$.

Answer (score 0):

Your first part of your proof is fine, as long as you have proved that the limit of a sequence of points in a closed set is part of that set.

There's a bit of a gap in the second part your proof.  Notice that you write:

> I assumed $p∈\bar{E}$ and that there does not exist a sequence $(p_n)⊆E$ such that $p_n→p$.

And then conclude:

> Then I concluded that there exists $ε>0$ such that $d(p,x)≥ε ∀x∈E$.

But this statement isn't immediately obvious.  What this part requires you to do is actually find a sequence $p_n \to p$.

One way to do this would be to take a sequence of positive real numbers $r_n$ converging to $0$ (like $(\frac{1}{n} )$) and for each real number, find an $x_n \in E$ such that $d(p,x_n) < r_n$ (you know that at least one exists since $\bar{E}$ is closed; $x_n$ might be $p$ itself: it may be useful to divide up cases for when $p \in E$ and when $p$ is a limit point).

> Then for any $\epsilon > 0$, simply find $N$ such that $\forall k \ge N$, $\epsilon > r_k > 0$ so that $d(p,x_k) < r_k < \epsilon$, proving convergence $x_n \to p$.